# Getting a 'modelformset_factory without defining 'fields' error' using Django inline formset. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

My **models.py** looks like this:

```
class Member(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    occupation = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class FamilyMember(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    relation = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    member = models.ForeignKey(Member)
```

I am trying to create an inline form for family members inside the members form. To do that, I am using `inlineformset_factory`:

```
from django import forms
from myapp.models import *
from django.forms.models import inlineformset_factory

class MemberForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Member
        fields = [
            'name', 'occupation',
        ]

FamilyMemberFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Member, FamilyMember)
```

When I run the server, I get the below error:

```
"Calling modelformset_factory without defining 'fields' or "
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Calling >modelformset_factory without defining 'fields' or 'exclude' explicitly is prohibited.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm not sure but I think you forgot to pass the form to `inlineformset_factory`:

```
FamilyMemberFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Member, FamilyMember, form=MemberForm)
```

Or you should specify what fields should be included/excluded using either `fields` parameter or `exclude`.

See some examples in [Django doc about inlineformset_factory](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets).

Comment: Alright, I added the parameter. But now I get this error : raise FieldError(message)
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (name, occupation, huge list of my data-fields.....) specified for FamilyMember

Comment: NVM, I think I got the problem.

Comment: Is it because your form should be for `FamilyMember` not `Member`?

Comment: Simply defining the fields fixed the problem.

Answer (score 5):

here you are:

```
FamilyMemberFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Member, FamilyMember, fields =['name', 'occupation',])
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/350567) by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.